# Sync objects between 2 buckets - User with read access on Source Bucket and Full Access on Destination Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have already seen a lot of answers where the user/role in the account (Account A) with `SourceBucket` have to add read policy to `DestinationBucket` and at the same time, the destination bucket should add a bucket policy to the user/role from Account A for read/write access.

But my problem is a bit different.

I have access to a user from Account A, which has only, the list and read access to `SourceBucket`. I also have full access to Account B and subsequently `DestinationBucket`.

Now what I can successfully do is `aws s3 sync` from bucket A to local drive using programmatic access to the user. And then use user/role from Account B to sync local drive to `DestinationBucket`.

I am trying to find a solution where I can directly sync between the 2 buckets without synchronizing it in a central storage.

What I have tried is creating a role in Account B which has read and write access to `DestinationBucket` and tried using Account A user to assume this role to have access to both `SourceBucket` and `DestinationBucket`, but I don't have permission to assume the role as well with this Account A user

Edit :
Based on the comments, adding a bit more information, which I have already tried. Hoping to get an answer now.

Following is the policy on the userA whose accesskey and secret I have, I can read contents of the source bucket using these key:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListSourceBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SourceBucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ReadSourceBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SourceBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Following is the bucket policy I have attached to DestinationBucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:user/userA"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DestinationBucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ReadAndPutObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:user/userA"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DestinationBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the userA don't have the policy of reading the `DestinationBucket` attached in its IAM policies, so the direct `aws s3 sync` command doesn't work. WHen I try that, it gives me the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't super clear still, essentially you want to sync from Account A to Account B and give Account B full control right?

Comment: I want to sync Account A to B that's right, but I have access to a user which has read right only on Account A bucket. Without doing a download and upload, and without adding an explicit IAM policy on account A to write to Bucket B, how can I sync it?

Comment: Do you mind adding a policy exception to your Account B s3 bucket? If that's fine happy to put an answer in for the config.

Comment: @pkarfs added more information. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there's three components here if you want to give Account B full control and Account A has read access and you don't want to / can't change explicit IAM policy or assume role.

1. Update your s3 bucket to allow Account A to sync objects to Account B.

   > Permissions should be the same as to what you already have mentioned in your question.
2. Give IAM permissions to Account A role to allow them to read objects in Account S3 and put objects on Account B.

   ```
   "Action": [   
           "s3:GetObjectVersion",
           "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
           "s3:ListObjectsV2",
           "s3:ListBucket"
           "s3:PutObjectAcl",
           "s3:PutObjectTagging",
           "s3:PutObject",
           "s3:GetObjectAcl",
           "s3:GetObjectTagging",
           "s3:GetObject"
           ]
   ```
3. Give permissions to Account B to have full control of s3 objects during sync cli command.

   > aws s3 sync . s3://{BUCKET} --acl bucket-owner-full-control

*Note: The sync command should be run from Account A role as it has read permissions on the bucket Account A bucket*

Comment: This involves modifying the IAM permission of userA which is not possible for me. 
Also, the ListObjectsV2 actions is invalid, its defined by ListBucket action

Comment: ListObjectsV2 isn't invalid, you just need to have it against the correct resource (which you can have bucket and bucket directories as two separate resources within the same SID policy) , was just listing the ones you'll need. Also are you unable to modify the IAM in Account A in its entirety?  If you can't then sync command won't work for you, instead use s3 cp. Which means your existing permissions should suffice.

Comment: s3:ListObjectsV2 is atleast invalid for me both on the bucket and the bucket content, I already had tried doing it and it said invalid action in both the location. Also, s3 cp gives me the following exception which is obvious as userA cant assume any role from account B  `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied`